# Netbeans Error Lock File Exist

Tags: netbeans

Guy's anybody can help me i have a problem in my netbeans 8.0.1, I cannot uninstall, there's an error message "A lock file exist at C:\Users\X\AppData\Roaming\Netbeans\8.0.1\lock".

Comment: Delete the file manually and then try again.

Comment: I tried it but there are file's that cannot be deleted. But anyway thanks.

Comment: Post the command you run to delete the lock file and the error message you get when you try to delete it.

Answer (score 17):

Delete that lock file. And uninstall.

Comment: This works but I had trouble accessing the .../Roaming folder. Typing `%appdata%` into the windows 10 search bar took me straight there.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue tonight. I searched for the file in my file explorer, and found it. I deleted the lock file, and was successfully able to run NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

I have locked that file and then uninstalled the Netbeans . Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with the lock file located at C:\Users\pcname\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2 you should delete it 
But it is located at Roaming folder which may not visible in your pc as it is a hidden folder follow the link open Roaming folder and other hidden folders
link:https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_files-insiderplat_pc/windows-10-roaming-folder/6c99ffdc-90d5-4d1d-8ab1-b4f448ecc8ee
unhide that folder and delete the file

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find lock file then just go to C:\Program Files (x86) and delete netbeans folder then it gets uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue but all I did was to unhide the hidden folders and files then I found that file visible then deleted it

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to uninstall

- 1st Delete %appdata%/Roaming/NetBeans/16/lock
- 2nd Rename or delete the folder %appdata%/Roaming/NetBeans/16/config

Answer (score 0):

Shut down related netbeans tasks from task manager,
Then delete the lock file using this command
del appdata/roaming/netbeans/18/lock

This retains all other settings and your installations on opening once again