# how can you delete a netbeans lock file

Tags: netbeans-8

When I try and save a NetBeans file, I get an error message similar to:

there were some problems while saving `xxx.cpp`

```
cause: cannot write to locked file:

    /home/xxx/xxx.cfg
```

I had to kill NetBeans because it froze, and it has left a lock file somewhere

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans Error Lock File Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404070/netbeans-error-lock-file-exist)

Comment: no, that is a question about installing netbeans, this is a question about saving code files